# How to display data form one db table to another db table's view page in php?

Tags: php

I have 2 db tables aspect & aspectdet_1. Each have Add, View, Edit & Delete pages.

Table: `aspect` has rows `ascode` & `asname`.

Table: `aspectdet_1` has rows `Dept_Code`, `ascode`, `astype`, `cndtn` & `asscope`.

I want to display `asname` from Table:`aspect` in  Table: `aspectdet_1`'s view page. 
I used the code

```
$query="SELECT aspectdet_1.Dept_Code, aspectdet_1.ascode, aspectdet_1.astype, aspectdet_1.cndtn, aspectdet_1.asscope, aspect.asname ".
    "FROM aspectdet_1, aspect ".
    "WHERE aspectdet_1.ascode = aspect.ascode ";
```

It works in view page.

But when I want to edit or delete that pages not supporting.

Is that code right?

What to do for edit & delete?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like database privilege problem. 
Please make sure whether **mysql-user** you used to connect to the databases (used in mysql_connet) has edit and delete privileges for the tables.

You can check the database table privileges in your **Phpmyadmin**

A nice tutorial about privileges:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html